bashコマンドライン実行とファイル実行での結果が異なる原因
やりたいこと
bashスクリプトで、aptパッケージのバージョン指定をしたリストファイルを読み込み、インストールを実行する作業を自動化したい。
環境
OS:Debian11
組み込みCPUボードにて実行
コード
スクリプトコード
#! /bin/sh
DEVELOP_DIR="/home/"
cd "$DEVELOP_DIR"
CURRENT=$(pwd)

echo '>> install apt packages'
APT_PKG_LIST="$DEVELOP_DIR/pkg_install_ver.list"

echo $APT_PKG_LIST
while read file_line
do
    str_array=($file_line)
    echo "${str_array[0]}=${str_array[1]}"
done < $APT_PKG_LIST

read -p "finish pat install. pres enter:"


pkg_install_ver.list
telnet 0.17-42
tree 1.8.0-1

実施したこと
コンソールでスクリプトコードを実行
##! /bin/sh
DEVELOP_DIR="/home/linaro/develop"
cd "$DEVELOP_DIR"
CURRENT=$(pwd)

echo '>> install apt packages'
APT_PKG_LIST="$DEVELOP_DIR/debian/pkg_install_ver.list"

echo $APT_PKG_LIST
while read file_line
do
    str_array=($file_line)
    echo "${str_array[0]}=${str_array[1]}"
done < $APT_PKG_LIST

read -p "finish pat install. pres enter:"


telnet=0.17-42
tree=1.8.0-1

意図したとおりに出力された。
スクリプトファイル(inst.sh)にして実行
※inst.shの内容は先に挙げたスクリプトコードが記述されています。
./inst.sh: 12: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")

どうやら配列にして代入する()部分がファイルからの実行すると構文エラーとなっているようです。
解決したいこと
()を使用せずにstr_arrayに配列として、ファイルから読み取ったパッケージ名とバージョンを代入したい。
なぜ同じスクリプトコードなのに、直接コマンドラインで入力すると良いのに、ファイル実行であるとえらーとなってしまうのでしょうか？

Debian の場合、/bin/sh の実体は dash でしょう。bash とは異なって dash では配列機能に対応していません。

type -a bash の結果は、/usr/bin/bash /bin/bashでした。type -a dashの結果は、/usr/bin/dash /bin/dashでした。shファイルの実行にはdashとなってしまうのでしょうか？

ls -l /bin/sh を実行してみてください。/bin/dash へのシンボリックリンクになっているかと思います。

inst.sh の shebang が #! /bin/sh となっていて、./inst.sh として実行していますので、inst.sh の内容は /bin/sh で実行されます。Debian のデフォルトの状態では /bin/sh は /bin/dash へのシンボリックリンクになっていますので、結果的に /bin/dash で実行されることになります。そして、dash には配列機能がありませんので、結果として syntax error になるわけです。

本当に ##! /bin/sh なら shebang にならないですよ・・・

##!  /bin/shの最初の#については、省略してしまいましたが、sudoユーザーのコンソール#を意味しており、root@debin:/home#の後にスクリプトコードをコピペで実行させております。

bash inst.shで正しく機能しました。

コメントでのご指摘により解決できました。
Debianでは、shファイルの実行時にはdashが実行されるため、配列が構文エラーとなるということです。
bashもインストールされているので、明示的に実行することで解決しました。
bash inst.sh


スクリプトの #! 行で bash を指定した方が良さそうな気もします。

POSIXシェルの祖先は shで, 移植性を重視して何処ででも動くようにするなら sh, 配列使いたいなどシェルそれぞれの機能使う分には(今回の場合では) bash (#!/usr/bin/env bash あるいは #!/usr/bin/bash) を shebangに指定したほうが良いでしょう
